# Repost "Word stays a word after taking away a letter"?

Tags: discussion, challenges, reposting

["Word stays a word after taking away a letter. Repeat"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145222/word-stays-a-word-after-taking-away-a-letter-repeat) was a massively downvoted question, not because of challenge, but mainly because it was badly written.
Personally, I think that the idea is great and it still has scope for many new answers, as it currently only has 4.
I think that we should repost the challenge, but with much more loose rules:

#### 1. Allow all languages

That's pretty obvious. The challenge only allowed Python, Ruby, Perl, Bash, or "whatever else often comes pre-installed on a Linux/Unix/Mac" answers. I think that caused at least half of the downvotes.

#### 2. Make it a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge

When the question was [first posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/145222/1), it was a [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), which I believe led to many downvotes too. But it was soon after edited to be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

#### 3. Take a dictionary *and a word* as the input

This is just my personal opinion, but I think it'll be more interesting to output if the word is a valid answer to the riddle, and not just output some random word that satisfies the riddle.

Opinions?

Comment: Why do you need permission? Is this not the same as situations where a the original is considered a "duplicate" of the newer, better challenge?

Comment: #thejonymyster Caird said it's better to ask on meta first, just to get feedback.

Comment: @thejonymyster Check the tag info for [\[reposting\]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/reposting/info); generally, unless a challenge is closed and very low quality, potential reposts should be asked about on meta first

Answer (score 7):

## I support this; especially with modification number three.

This seems like it could be a very interesting challenge idea. It could do with a reopening. Number three would additionally make it a lot more interesting.

Also, (tossing it out there) perhaps another input could be to specify what counts as a glyph (character, letter, unit of writing)? Digraphs (two-character glyphs) & trigraphs (three-character glyphs) would be interesting cases to handle.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand what you mean by glyphs, digraphs and trigraphs.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I hope it is clearer now!